# How to retrieve user's friend list and show in TableView with swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I'm using parse and I'm able to save user's friend that user added in current user's object but I don't know how to retrieve current user's friend list and show them in tableview so how can I get that list from current user's object and display it in tableview with parse in swift. (My app doesn't have anything to do with Facebook at all). 
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

EDIT: The OP posted some code in the comments, i formatted it into the question:

```
var query = PFUser.query();
var currentUser = PFQuery(className:"User");
currentUser.whereKey("currentUser", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()) currentUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in 
    if error == nil { 
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

I've managed to save friend that user added in PFRelation but I can't manage to show user list in my tableview.My tableview didn't show any username of the current user account

Comment: a quick scan of the parse api does not show a global current user object. it seems that you can only retrieve what you saved earlier? so accessing the contacts or friends list seems impossible unless you saved all those contacts from inside your app? please specify the exact problem you are experiencing, and if possible show some code.

Comment: I want to retrieve user's friend list for each account after I login,so different account can retrieve different friend list but I don't know which method or code to make this work.

Comment: you will have to answer my questions if you want my help. why do you expect this user object to have a friends list in the first place? did you save any contacts to the usersObject? the api shows a function to get the users facebook friends if they logged in using facebook, but you said this is not the case. also, i need to see code in order to help. if you dont know which code to show, just post all of it. ill find the part i need to see.

Comment: var query = PFUser.query()
        var currentUser = PFQuery(className:"User")
        currentUser.whereKey("currentUser", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
        currentUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
             self.tableView.reloadData()                                                                            I've managed to save friend that user added in PFRelation but I can't manage to show user list in my tableview.My tableview didn't show any username of the current user account.

Comment: Ok, two things about ettiquette on SO: Please dont ever dump your code on someone ike this. Put it in a code section into your question, it will be much more readable. i fixed that for you. Second, when people try to help you and ask questions in the process, please answer them, as specific as possible. just rephriasing your question is very unlikely to succeed. Anyways, i posted an attempted answer, see if it helps you

Answer (score 1):

you may want to check this post on parse.com, which explains how `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` works:

https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-use-findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock-properly-and-be-able-to-cache-the-result

Long story short, you seem to not be updating the tableViews dataSource before calling `reloadData`. make the array that populates yout tableVIew contain the objects that `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`returns, then call reloadData. Best of luck and welcome to SO!